How to spy on useAppDispatch() hook instance using redux-toolkit vitest
Since we can not use the hook useAppDispatch() within our test file, I wonder how can I spy on the returned instance.
import * as redux from "@/core/context/redux/store";

...
it("test",async ()=>{
    await waitFor(() => {
      wrapper = render(<MockForgeViewer />);
    });
    const spyDispatch = vi.spyOn(redux, "useAppDispatch");
    wrapper?.unmount();
    expect(spyDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
   
});

What I've just realized is that what this code is spying on the hook itself rather than the returned value (dispatch)
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

indeed I wish to spy on dispatch to assert when a specific reducer has been called. Eg:
dispatch(resetStates());



it("test",async ()=>{
    await waitFor(() => {
      wrapper = render(<MockForgeViewer />);
    });
    const spyDispatch = vi.spyOn(redux, "useAppDispatch");
    wrapper?.unmount();
    expect(spyDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
   
});

What I've just realized is that what this code is spying on the hook
itself rather than the returned value (dispatch)

You should create a mock dispatch function to assert on, returned by your useAppDispatch spy.
Example:
const mockDispatch = vi.fn();
const spyDispatch = vi.spyOn(redux, "useAppDispatch")
  .mockImplementation(() => mockDispatch);

...

expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(resetStates());


Thanks much! I completely missed mocking the spy returned value and asserting on it.

@MiguelG Welcome, happy to help. Cheers!
